# Does $p$-adic Baker theorem holds in the given case?

Tags: nt.number-theory, class-field-theory, p-adic-numbers, transcendental-number-theory

Let $p$ be a prime number, $\mathbb{Q}_p$ the field of $p$-adic numbers, and $\mathbb{C}_p$ the completion of the algebraic closure of $\mathbb{Q}_p$. Let $U_p$ be the units $(1+\mathfrak{m})$ of $\mathbb{C}_p$, the $p$-adic version of Baker theorem is:

---

**Theorem** ([Brumer](https://londmathsoc.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1112/S0025579300003703)):
Let $\alpha_1, \cdots, \alpha_n$ be elements of principal units $U_p$ which are algebraic over the rationals $\mathbb{Q}$ and their $p$-adic logarithms $\log_p(\alpha_1), \cdots, \log_p(\alpha_n)$ are linearly independent over $\mathbb{Q}$. Then $\log_p(\alpha_1), \cdots, \log_p(\alpha_n)$ are then linearly independent over the algebraic closure $A$ of $\mathbb{Q}$ in $\mathbb{C}_p$.

---

I am confused if the above result is the true the $p$-adic version of [Baker theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baker%27s_theorem) or not because [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baker%27s_theorem#Extensions) says the Baker's theorem in $p$-adic setting is an open problem.

Anyway, I want to construct an example where the above theorem(Brumer) holds:

Fix $p=2$, and assume, $K=\mathbb Q_2(\sqrt{-1})$ with uniformizer $\pi=-1+\sqrt{-1}$ and "restrict" ourselves on the principal units $U=1+\mathfrak{m}_K$, where $\mathfrak{m}_K$ is the maximal ideal of $K$. Further, assume we know a basis $\{2\pi, 4\}$ of $\log_2(U)$, where $\log_2$ is the $2$-adic logarithm. Take $\alpha_1, \alpha_2, \cdots, \alpha_n$ in the principal units $U_1=1+\mathfrak{m}_K$ of the quadratic extension $K$ satisfying the Brumer theorem above i.e., are algebraic over the rationals $\mathbb{Q}$ and their $2$-adic logarithm $\log_2(\alpha_1), \cdots, \log_2(\alpha_n)$ are linearly independent over $\mathbb{Q}$ for $n=2$. My question:

> Does the above theorem holds in the given situation? i.e., Are $\log_1(\alpha_1), \log_2(\alpha_2)$ linearly independent over the algebraic closure $A$ of $\mathbb{Q}$ in $\mathbb{Q}_2$  ?

---

We have given the basis $\{2 \pi, 4\}$ of $\log_2(U)$, and therefore $\log_2(\alpha_1), \log_2(\alpha_2)$ all can be obtained by linear combination of the basis $\{2\pi, 4 \}$, where the  uniformizer is $\pi=-1+\sqrt{-1}$. So we can write
\begin{align}
 &\log_2(\alpha_1)=2 \pi a_1+4b_1, \log_2(\alpha_2)=2 \pi a_2+4b_2
\\ \Rightarrow &\log_2(\alpha_1)=(-2a_1+4b_1)+\sqrt{-1} \cdot 2a_1, \cdots, \log_2(\alpha_n2)=(-2a_2+4b_2)+ \sqrt{-1} \cdot 2a_2
\end{align}
for scalars $a_i,b_i \in \mathbb{Z}_2$.

Since $\sqrt{-1} \notin \mathbb{Q}_2$, I think $\log_2(\alpha_1), \log_2(\alpha_2)$ are linearly independent over the algebraic closure $A$ of $\mathbb{Q}$ in $\mathbb{Q}_2$ because for scalars (not all zero) $\beta_1, \beta_2, \cdots, \beta_n \in \mathbb{Q}$ the linear combination
\begin{align*}
    &\beta_1 \log_2(\alpha_1)+\cdots+\beta_2 \log_2(\alpha_2) \neq 0 \\
    \Rightarrow &  \beta_1((-2a_1+4b_1)+\sqrt{-1} \cdot 2a_1)+\cdots+2 \beta_2((-2a_2+4b_2)+\sqrt{-1} \cdot 2a_2) \neq 0,
\end{align*}
where $\beta_i \in \mathbb{Q}$ and $a_i,b_i \in \mathbb{Z}_2$.

The logarithms $\log_2(\alpha_1), \log_2(\alpha_2)$ will be "linearly independent" over $A=\bar{Q} \cap \mathbb Q_2$. The question remains

> Can we talk about "algebraic independence" of the logarithms $\log_2(\alpha_1), \log_2(\alpha_2)$ ?

So it seems this example works. I appreciate your comments/answers.

Comment: That page on wikipedia is saying that the algebraic independence of logarithms is an open problem both over complex numbers and over p-adic. The Baker's theorem over p-adic is very well known and the estimates are on par with estimates in the complex case.

Comment: @OlegEroshkin, thanks. So algebraic independence is not known over $\mathbb Q_p$ or $\bar{\mathbb Q}_p$ in the $p$-adic setting. Anyway, does my example work here, at least for the Brumer theorem ?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your question. Algebraic independence over some field $K$ is the same as over the algebraic closure $\bar{K}$. Regarding your question, if $\log_p(\alpha_i)$ are linear combinations over $\mathbb{Q}$ of 2 numbers and $n>2$, then they are linearly dependent over $\mathbb{Q}$. It's a basic linear algebra.

Comment: @OlegEroshkin, Sorry, I couldn't understand. In your 1st comment said "algebraic independence of $p$-dic logarithms is an open problem over $p$-adic". what does mean by it ?

Comment: I think you may be confusing the definitions of *linear dependence* and *algebraic dependence*. Baker's theorem and it's generalizations are about linear independence of logarithms, but of course, one can write $\sum a_i\log(b_i)=0$ as $\prod b_i^{a_i}=1$ with appropriate choices of branches of the exponentials, so one can translate Baker's theorem into products. What is open is algebraic indpendence of the logarithms with appropriate hypotheses.

Comment: @JoeSilverman, very nice. I understand. So we don't know about algebraic independence of the $p$-adic logarithms. As for linear independence, why my example fails to hold Brumer theorem (above) for $n>2$ ?

Comment: @ANG Let me explain with a simple example. Numbers $2+\alpha$, $3+2\alpha$, and $5+11\alpha$ are linearly dependent over $\mathbb{Q}$ even if $\alpha$ is irrational. You assume that if $\sqrt{-1}$ is not in your field, the linear combinations with it are linearly independent is false.

Comment: @OlegEroshkin, thank you very much. I understand these logarithms in my example are not LI for $n > 2$, but my question was really in different direction. why Brumer theorem is failing in my example, for $n > 2$ ? Because Brumer theorem is supposed to hold since it is a general statement. I think  LI holds on $A =\bar{\mathbb{Q}} \cap \mathbb Q_2$ not simply on $\mathbb Q$ in Brumer theorem. Can you please comment on this ? By the way, there is still a chance that the logarithm in my example can be algebraically independent (AI) because LI and AI are separate things. What do you say ?

Comment: @ANG What do you mean: theorem is failing? A conclusion of a theorem is true if the conditions are satisfied. One of the conditions of Brumer's theorem is " logs are independent over $\mathbb{Q}$". That's false in your case. So the theorem is not failing - it's not applicable.

Comment: @OlegEroshkin, ahh, thanks. I am silly. Yes my example is not satisfying the conditions of Brumer theorem. Or, we can say my example satisfies Brumer theorem for $n=2$.  I got it. Can you make any comment on the last sentence of my previous comment ? thanks

Comment: @ANG Algebraic independence is a much stronger condition than linear independence. If numbers are linearly dependent over $\mathbb{Q}$ they are (trivially) algebraically dependent as well.

Comment: @OlegEroshkin, just confirm me. In my example $\log_2(\alpha_1)$ and $\log_2(\alpha_2)$ are linearly independent over $\mathbb Q$. So Brumer theorem satisfies, and so by Brumer theorem (above) $\log_2(\alpha_1)$ and $\log_2(\alpha_2)$ are also linearly independent over $\bar {\mathbb Q} \cap \mathbb Q_2$. And the last conclusion is indeed true because $\sqrt{-1} \notin \mathbb Q_2$. Am I right ?

Comment: @ANG The fact that $\sqrt{-1}$ is not in $\mathbb{Q}_2$ is irrelevant here. If logs of $\alpha_1$ and $\alpha_2$ are linearly independent over $\mathbb{Q}$ then they are independent over the algebraic closure $A$ of $\mathbb{Q}$ in $\Omega_2$ (which contains $\sqrt{-1}$).

Comment: @OlegEroshkin, thanks, but i don't see how logs of $\alpha_1$ and $\alpha_2$ are L.I. over the algebraic closure $A$ of $\mathbb Q$ in $\Omega_2$. Though it should be, but I don't see how

Comment: @ANG That is the conclusion of Brumer theorem.